# LINQ to SQL Table List to Interface List

Tags: linq-to-sql, interface

I have the following code:

```
public IQueryable<ITax> FindAllTaxes()
{
      return db.Taxes;
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Models.Tax>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Interfaces.ITax>'
```

I am trying to use Interface where ever I go, but not sure how to convert this, any help?

Comment: For info - in the stackoverflow editor; if you indent the code blocks 4 spaces (or hit the code icon) it'll render correctly, including the all-important < > escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have covariance of generic types yet, I'm afraid. You can do `IQueryable<Tax>`, but not `IQueryable<ITax>`. You could introduce a conversion, but it'll probably break composability, rendering it useless. You could try it though:

```
return db.Taxes.Cast<ITax>();
```

In C# 4.0, this would probably work without the extra cast (although I haven't tried it).

Comment: Amazing how a little formatting can change the sense of a question.  I was scratching my head over why IQueryable (non-generic) wouldn't work and lo and behold, it was really a generic of the interface he was after.

Comment: I had the same - I started writing an answer about how Table<T> : IQueryable<T> : IQueryable, then thought "I wonder..." ;-p

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     public IQueryable<Taxe> FindAllTaxes() { return db.Taxes; }
```

or

```
     public IQueryable<Tax> FindAllTaxes() { return db.Taxes; }
```